# angular file upload with ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am uploading image file using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) for image upload. using the example given, I encountered access-control header error.

```
    vm.uploadPic = function(file) {
      file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/quotes/quoteitem/image/upload',
      data: {quote_item_id: vm.quote_item_id, filename: file}
    });
   }
```

This gives error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/v1/quotes/quoteitem/image/upload. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I don't need any header request while uploading image in postman so, I removed header.

```
vm.uploadPic = function(file) {
  file.upload = Upload.upload({
    url: domain+'/api/v1/quotes/quoteitem/image/upload',
    data: {quote_item_id: vm.quote_item_id, filename: file},
    transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
       var headers = headersGetter();
       headers['Content-type']=undefined;
       return headers;
    }

  });
}
```

This gives

> TypeError: data.hasOwnProperty is not a function
>       at ng-file-upload.js:310
>       at angular.js:10484
>       at forEach (angular.js:322)
>       at transformData (angular.js:10483)
>       at $get.serverRequest (angular.js:11211)
>       at processQueue (angular.js:15961)
>       at angular.js:15977
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:17229)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:17045)
>       at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:17337)

I am stuck in this for quite a time now. I have tested in server side and it works fine in postman. Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Your server needs to allow CORS for POST and OPTIONS. The error message is clear. Look at the response content from the server from the network tab of your browser and make sure the options request is returned with proper headers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are uploading from the site at port 3000 to an endpoint at port 8000. These are considered separate origins, so the browser's security features are kicking in. You either need to get them on the same origin, or add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the server-side response of the upload endpoint.

Comment: I have done cors setup in the server side. All other routes are accessible but only this is not allowed.

Comment: Try setting them up to run on the same port, if you can. If it works, that will prove there is nothing wrong with your Angular code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these one

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(data){
            alert("success");
        })
        .error(function(data){
              alert("error");
        });
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('fupController', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', '$http', function($scope, fileUpload, $http){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is '+ file );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/quotes/quoteitem/image/upload';
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };



}]);
```

Comment: No files are recieved by the servers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851149/how-to-upload-image-in-local-path-using-angularjs-mean-stack

Comment: if u know how to store image into local storage

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-controller="commentCtrl" name="form">
    <a href="" type="file" class="custom-height"><img src="source/assets/images/icons/icofileattached.png" class="attachmentpng-height"  ngf-select="uploadFiles($file)" ng-model="files"/></a>
    <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised custom-submit-button" ng-click="MakeComments()"> SUBMIT </md-button>
    </form>


$scope.uploadFiles = function(file) {
            console.log(file);
            $scope.fileData = file;
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            Restangular.one('/api/files/end points').withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})
                .customPOST(fd, '', undefined, {'Content-Type': undefined})
        };
```